# Rounded corners at the bottom of the window?

Tags: themes, window-manager, window

Is there a tutorial for beginners on how to rounded bottom corners of the window?

Like the Mac OS to the example.

Comment: Please edit your post and tell us what programming language you intend to use and what gui library.

Answer (score 0):

There are now ways to tell the default theme to use 4 rounded corners. You should look for an another theme.

As you probably know, there are many Ubuntu variants. Assuming that you are using Ubuntu with Unity, then you are looking for a theme for Compiz. Compiz is the name of the "window decorator", i.e. the program that draws window borders.

You can find many themes on [compiz-themes.org](http://compiz-themes.org/). Giving a quick look, I could find one that may fit your tastes: [AmbianceBLUISH](http://compiz-themes.org/content/show.php/AmbianceBLUISH+1.0?content=150442). It is very similar to the default, but adds rounded corners and a few other tweaks.